# Easiest way to create a matrix with pre-determined dimension and values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix with dimention (2,5) and I have have a vector of values to be fill in that matrix. What is the best way. I can think of three methods but I have trouble using the `np.empty & fill` and `np.full` without loops

```
x=np.array(range(0,10))
mat=x.reshape(2,5)

array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

mat=np.empty((2,5))
newMat=mat.fill(x)   # Error: The x has to be scalar

mat=np.full((2,5),x)   # Error: The x has to be scalar
```

Comment: What's wrong with `np.copy`?

Comment: What's wrong with the `x.reshape`?

Comment: It is not at all clear what values you are trying to put into the 2x5 matrix. Which are you trying to use without success? Your example of 0 through 9 was a success: give at least one example without success of your desired result.

Comment: @aryamccarthy I  am not aware of np. copy. thanks

Comment: @wim I am just curious. Because when I google to create matrix with python, the np.empty and fill show in most results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`full` and `fill` are for setting all elements the same

```
In [557]: np.full((2,5),10)
Out[557]: 
array([[10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]])
```

Assigning an array works provided the shapes match (in the broadcasting sense):

```
In [558]: arr[...] = x.reshape(2,5)   # make source the same shape as target
In [559]: arr
Out[559]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [560]: arr.flat = x    # make target same shape as source
In [561]: arr
Out[561]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

`arr.flat` and `arr.ravel()` are equivalent.  Well, not quite:

```
In [562]: arr.flat = x.reshape(2,5)   # don't need the [:] with flat @wim
In [563]: arr
Out[563]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [564]: arr.ravel()[:] = x.reshape(2,5)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,5) into shape (10)
In [565]: arr.ravel()[:] = x.reshape(2,5).flat
```

`flat` works with any shape source, even ones that require replication

```
In [570]: arr.flat = [1,2,3]
In [571]: arr
Out[571]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
       [3, 1, 2, 3, 1]])
```

More broadcasted inputs

```
In [572]: arr[...] = np.ones((2,1))
In [573]: arr
Out[573]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
In [574]: arr[...] = np.arange(5)
In [575]: arr
Out[575]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

---

An example of the problem Eric mentioned.  The ravel (or other reshape) of a transpose is (often) a copy.  So writing to that does not modify the original.

```
In [578]: arr.T.ravel()[:]=10
In [579]: arr
Out[579]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
In [580]: arr.T.flat=10
In [581]: arr
Out[581]: 
array([[10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]])
```

Comment: Writing to `arr.ravel()` is a bad idea, because unlike `.flat`, it is not always a view

Comment: It's not necessary to slice the `flatiter` object.

Answer (score 1):

[`ndarray.flat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) returns an object which can modify the contents of the array by direct assignment:

```
>>> array = np.empty((2,5), dtype=int)
>>> vals = range(10)
>>> array.flat = vals
>>> array
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

If that seems kind of magical to you, then read about the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set__).

*Warning:* assigning to flat does not raise exceptions for size mismatch.  If there are not enough values on the right hand side of the assignment, the data will be rolled/repeated.  If there are too many values, only the first few will be used.

Comment: Usually, how does one fill up the np.empty array? Using loop is the the only way?

Comment: You can use `__setitem__` as usual, but you need to use an object which can be broadcast to the required shape on the right hand side.  Loops are **not** required, and should generally be avoided in numpy.

Comment: `ravel()` is _not_ guaranteed to return a view (`array[:1,:4].ravel()` does not), so this is risky

Comment: Oh, OK, but it's safe in the use-case described here ... isn't it?  I've edited to use `ndarray.flat` instead which seems a better choice, regardless.

Answer (score -2):

If you want a 10x2 matrix of 5:

```
np.ones((10,2))*5
```

If you have a list of values and just want them in a particular shape:

```
datavalues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
np.reshape(datavalues,(2,5))

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Comment: What if I want the elements inside the matrix to be different.

Comment: This has the same effect as `full` because it fills with a scalar value.